# react native why is my condition not working?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I want to show components when one of the three product categorys are selected.

Its not working.

```
 { step === 2 && (product.category.category_name === 'clothing') || (product.category.category_name === 'accessoires') || (product.category.category_name === 'shoes') && return (<View><Text>Hello</Text></View> ) }
```

If clothing or accessoires or shoes exists then I want to show a component. Its not working why ? If I remove all except clothing then it works.

Comment: Mixing `&&` and `||` without proper `()` is not a good practice and it will very likely cause confusion and errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should chain better your conditionals `&&` and `||`.

Try this code:

```
if (step === 2) 
{ 
 if (product.category.category_name === 'clothing' ||
     product.category.category_name === 'accessoires' ||
     product.category.category_name === 'shoes' )
   { 
     return (<View><Text>Hello</Text></View> )
   }
 }
```

Comment: Even, better answer: Create an array with the possible string's value and change the conditionals in this way:  const arrayItems = ['clothing','accessoires','shoes','item3','item4'] 

Then,

if (step === 2 && arrayItems.includes(product.category.category_name.toLowerCase()) ) { return (<View><Text>Hello</Text></View> ) }